# Unified way for resolving dependencies / constructor injection

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs, xlabs

In my point of view it is a little confusing how to resolve dependecies in XLabs.

According to the sample project here is how I register the dependencies (simplified):

1) Platform **dependent** in [MainActivity.cs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample.Droid/MainActivity.cs):

```
private void SetIoc()
{
    var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();
    resolverContainer.Register<IMediaPicker, MediaPicker>();
    Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
}
```

2) Platform **independent** in [App.cs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/App.cs):

```
public App ()
{
    DependencyService.Register<ISettings, Settings>();
    DependencyService.Register<FooViewModel>();
}
```

---

Now, it is rather difficult to resolve the dependencies. The expected way would be resolving by constructor injection, which ends in exceptions:

```
public FooViewModel(IMediaPicker picker) {} // Exception
public FooViewModel(ISettings settings) {} // Exception
```

Another, but not optimum way is to resolve by DependencyService / Resover. But here I need to know which I have to use:

```
public FooViewModel()
{
    _picker = Resolver.Resolve<IMediaPicker>();
    _settings = DependencyService.Get<ISettings>();
}
```

This all seems not optimal for me (e.g. for unit testing). Is there a way to unify the whole resolving process, in the best case via constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Theres not reason not to place your implementations in your constructors and pass them down the stack. Define your Interface in your PCL implement it in your Android or IOS specific projects and pass it into the PCL on you APP constructor. It will work fine.

The problem arises though when you start to have more then about 3 interfaces you want to be platform specific. When the constructor of your App starts to get longer then the constructor of your MainPage you might start looking for other options.

DependencyService is a simple low ball container that Xamarin Forms offers you. You can use it for platform specific or within the PCL. It takes simple forms. You register your interface and the implementation you want to use for it and then you can retrieve a new instance of the implementation anywhere in your PCL or platform specific code. It's simple to use.
Register with

```
DependencyService.Register<IMyInterface,MyClass> ();
```

Get an instance of MyClass just call

```
IMyInterface me = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface> ();
```

and me will be a brand new baby MyClass.

You could also call it in your Platform specific code.

```
DependencyService.Register<IMyInterface,MyAndroidVersion> ();
```

and then in your PCL

```
IMyInterface me = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface> ();
```

would give you MyAndroid version.

XLabs Container works the same way just gives you more options. You don't have to use both in fact I'd recommend against it. Pick one of the three options and use it. If you start with the first two you could eventually outgrow them so XLabs might be the best choice.

Personally I use the SimpleIOC container from MVVMLight. But they are all basically the same thing just with a few different bells and whistles.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. A little help could be to use the `DependencyService.Register<T, TImpl>()` method within my platform specific project. I will give it a try. But this is still not the best way in my point of view. Optimal would be to have a Dependency injection container which resolves all dependencies in the constructor. Then it is not necessary to pass all implementations from the top down the stack. Actually I expected at this line of code `Resolver.SetResolver(IResolver resolver)` to configure the container to doing this, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: In my Projects I generally register all my Platform specific dependencies in the constructor of my MainPage and all my PCL dependencies in the constructor of my App.Of course you dont have to do it that way but I would personnally consider it a best practice. Having registrations scattered all over the app would be a pain.